# Why Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot properly

Tags: 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my dell precision 5530. After the installation the GNU GRUB menu appears instead of login screen. 
Typing

```
ls (hd0,1)/efi/
```

it shows

```
ubuntu/ boot/ Dell/
```

folders. And inside the boot folder:

```
bootx64.efi fbx64.efi
```

Here is the bios menu:

[image]

There is no PPT options.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you turn off the PPT option in BIOS?

Comment: PPT does not exist. I can not find it, even in the security section.

Comment: @Raffles I've updated my post.

Comment: Try  Secure Boot > Secure Boot Enable, choose Disabled.

Comment: It is also disabled

Comment: Can you also check > System Configuration > SATA Operation > AHCI > Confirm

Comment: Also in AHCI mode. I really do not know, what shoud I do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107193/discussion-between-raffles-and-zero-coding).